# swift variable param compare with array

Tags: swift, variadic-functions

`func gradientOfView(withColours: UIColor..., locations: [NSNumber])`

`func gradientOfView(withColours: [UIColor], locations: [NSNumber])`

Which is better?

When to use variable param replace array as param?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

variadic function accept 0 or more parameters, see next snippet

```
func f0(items: Any...) {
    print(type(of: items))
    items.forEach { (i) in
        print("\t",i)
    }
}

func f1(items: [Any]) {
    print(type(of: items))
    items.forEach { (i) in
        print("\t",i)
    }
}

f0(items: 1,2)
f1(items: [1,2])

f0(items: [1,2])
f1(items: [1,2])

f0()
```

it prints

```
Array<Any>
     1
     2
Array<Any>
     1
     2
Array<Any>
     [1, 2]
Array<Any>
     1
     2
Array<Any>
```

the statement

```
f1()
```

will produce an error on compilation
If you don't have very good reason to declare the function with a variadic parameter, avoid it.